# In GitHub Actions is it possible to pass steps to a sub-action?

Tags: github-actions, modularity

Is there any way that a step in a workflow job can specify sub-steps to pass to a custom action?

```
steps:
  - uses: ...
    with:
      steps:
        - ...
        - ...
  - ...
```

For example, a `uses: actions/cache@v2` will attempt to download a snapshot immediately (in the current step), and also inserts a `post` step to upload a fresh snapshot *after all other steps in the parent job*. This works well for build processes that (through multiple stages) intelligently recognise which objects need to be recreated and which do not. But it is not suited for workflows that need to set up a clean environment (or generate test data) that may then be manipulated by the tests. I'd like to make a different cache action, that is explicitly passed instructions for how to regenerate the cache from scratch, and which uploads the state *before* returning to the following step of the parent action.

Is there any way this could be achieved? (Composite actions? Advanced yaml syntax? Template expressions? Low-level actions toolkits/features? Implementing an interpreter to re-parse the input parameter?)